# Suppose $F = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, for $i = 1,...,n$. Prove that $\sqrt[3]2 \not\in F$.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $F = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, for $i = 1,...,n$. Prove that $\sqrt[3]2 \not\in F$.

**Attempt:** Suppose $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finte extension and let $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)$ be a subfield of F containing $\mathbb{Q}$.
Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2): \mathbb{Q}] = 3$

And $[F : \mathbb{Q}]$, depending if $i $ is even or odd will have a different value.

I was hoping to find a contradiction in finding $[F : \mathbb{Q}]$, so that 
$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2): \mathbb{Q}] = 3$ does not divide $[F : \mathbb{Q}]$.
But I am having trouble in finding $[F : \mathbb{Q}]$ , so that $\sqrt[3]2 \not\in F$.

Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: Since each $\alpha_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, you have $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_i) : \mathbb{Q}] = 1,2$ for each $\alpha_i$, so $[F : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^k$ for some $k \geq 0$.

Comment: Perhaps a little more should be said, since the same is not true if each $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_i)$ has degree $3$.  In any case, $F$ can be obtained by a sequence of quadratic extensions.

Comment: So we would have a contradiction because 3 does not divide $2^k$. However , I am still having difficulty on understanding why $[F: \mathbb{Q}] = 2^k$.

Comment: You can adjoin each $\alpha_i$ one at a time, and each extension will have degree $2$ or $1$, so by the tower law, the whole extension has degree $2^k$. In other words, you can write $F$ as
$$F = K_{n-1}(\alpha_n),$$
where $K_{n-1} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-1})$. And similarly, you can write $K_{n-1} = K_{n-2}(\alpha_{n-1})$, where $K_{n-2} = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-2})$... and so on and so forth, and each extension $K_{i}$ has degree $1$ or $2$ over $K_{i - 1}$. Then apply the tower law to find $[F : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^k$.

Comment: thank you for the explanation ! you could have made it an answer

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Might I suggest you turn your comments into an answer. This may help to remove this question from the unanswered que. If you do, you can post a link to your answer [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers) to draw some attention to it and possibly get some upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjoin each $\alpha_i$ one at a time, and each extension will have degree $2$ or $1$, so by the tower law, the whole extension has degree $2^k$. In other words, you can write $F$ as
$$F=K_{n−1}(\alpha_n),$$
where $K_{n−1}= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,…,\alpha_{n−1})$. And similarly, you can write $K_{n−1} = K_{n−2}(\alpha_{n−1})$, where $K_{n−2} = (\alpha_1,…,\alpha_{n−2})$,... and so on and so forth, and each extension $K_i$ has degree $1$ or $2$ over $K_{i−1}$. Then apply the tower law to find $[F : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^k$.